# Remove 'u' from a python list

Tags: python

I have a python list of list as follows. I want to flatten it to a single list.

```
l = [u'[190215]']
```

I am trying.

```
l = [item for value in l for item in value]
```

It turns the list to `[u'[', u'1', u'9', u'0', u'2', u'1', u'5', u']']`

How to remove the `u` from the list.

Comment: output like l = ['[190215]'] ??

Comment: `l` is a single list, consisting of one element, and that element is of type `unicode`.  It's a string that looks like `[190215]`, it's not a list whose element is the number `190215`.  Can you say exactly what you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your current code, you are iterating on a string, which represents a list, hence you get the individual characters.

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> l = [u'[190215]']
>>> l = [item for value in l for item in value]
>>> l
[u'[', u'1', u'9', u'0', u'2', u'1', u'5', u']']
```

Seems to me, you want to convert the inner string representation of list, to a flattened list, so here you go:

```
>>> l = [u'[190215]']
>>> l = [item for value in l for item in literal_eval(value)]
>>> l
[190215]
```

---

The above will work only when all the inner lists are strings:

```
>>> l = [u'[190215]', u'[190216, 190217]']
>>> l = [item for value in l for item in literal_eval(value)]
>>> l
[190215, 190216, 190217]
>>> l = [u'[190215]', u'[190216, 190217]', [12, 12]]
>>> l = [item for value in l for item in literal_eval(value)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

Answer (score 12):

The `u` means a [`unicode`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) string which should be perfectly fine to use.
But if you want to convert `unicode` to `str` (which just represents plain bytes in Python 2) then you may `encode` it using a character encoding such as `utf-8`.

```
>>> items = [u'[190215]']
>>> [item.encode('utf-8') for item in items]
['[190215]']
```

Answer (score 5):

use `[str(item) for item in list]`

example

```
>>> li = [u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd']
>>> print li
[u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd']
>>> li_u_removed = [str(i) for i in li]
>>> print li_u_removed
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: `result1.append([str(i) for i in line])`
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 56-59: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: The original data which I want to be converted to normal string 
file csv >> result  `[u'"0000211504512150"', u'"NEW"', u'"27.95"', u'"sdjfgjdshf"', u'"0"', u'"FALSE"', u'""', u'""', u'"adfgugfius708vs"', u'"FBR"', u'"FALSE"', u'"NOT_PUBLISHED"', u'""']`..... like 
file csv >> result  `["0000211504512150", "NEW", "27.95", "sdjfgjdshf", "0", "FALSE", "", "", "adfgugfius708vs", "FBR", "FALSE", "NOT_PUBLISHED", ""] `

Answer (score 4):

You can convert your unicode to normal string with `str` :

```
>>> list(str(l[0]))
['[', '1', '9', '0', '2', '1', '5', ']']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue occurred in `python 2.7` but in latest python version **u** did not displayed when it run

```
l = [u'[190215]']
l = [item for value in l for item in value]
print(l)
```

**output -:** `['[', '1', '9', '0', '2', '1', '5', ']']`

If you want to **concatenate** string items in a list into a single string, you can try this code

```
l = [u'[190215]']
l = [item for value in l for item in value]
l = ''.join(l)
print(l)
```

**output -:** `[190215]`