# What is the simplest way to remove unicode 'u' from a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, unicode

I have a list like this

```
d=[{u'Length': u'2.96m', u'Width': u'1.44m', u'height': u'0.38m'},
{u'Length': u'3.8m', u'Width': u'0.65m', u'height': u'9.3m'},
{u'Length': u'0.62m', u'Width': u'2.9m', u'height': u'3.5m'}]
```

and I want a simple way to remove unicode 'u' from this list to create a new list. The "simple way" here I ment to remove unicode without importing an external module or saving it in external files.

These are the five methods I tried

```
def to_utf8(d):
    if type(d) is dict:
        result = {}
        for key, value in d.items():
            result[to_utf8(key)] = to_utf8(value)
    elif type(d) is unicode:
        return d.encode('utf8')
    else:
        return d


#these three returns AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
d.encode('utf-8')
d.encode('ascii')
d.encode("ascii","replace")

#output the same
to_utf8(d)
print str(d)
```

firs three returns

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

and last two prints the same result. How should I remove unicode 'u'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove 'u' from a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975911/remove-u-from-a-python-list)

Comment: Use str() function to convert it to string.

Comment: @JayParikh tried dosent work

Comment: @Eka it works. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the simplest solution

```
d=[{u'Length': u'2.96m', u'Width': u'1.44m', u'height': u'0.38m'},
{u'Length': u'3.8m', u'Width': u'0.65m', u'height': u'9.3m'},
{u'Length': u'0.62m', u'Width': u'2.9m', u'height': u'3.5m'}]

def to_utf8(d):
    final = []
    for item in d:
        if type(item) is dict:
            result = {}
            for key, value in item.items():
                result[str(key)] = str(value)
            final.append(result)
    return final

print to_utf8(d)
```

Comment: No, this is not the simplest way. Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45206700/7738328 is simpler, at least in my book.

Answer (score 3):

How about this, iterate list and encode each key, value in dictionary.

```
converted = [{ str(key): str(value)
                for key, value in array.items() 
            } for array in d]

print (converted)
```

Comment: It would probably be better to do `str(...)` rather than `.encode('utf-8')` as `unicode` and `str` are not the same type in Python 2.

Comment: This answer use `encode("utf-8")` at first. And the advantage of this answer must be the list comprehension. And the `str` must be borrowed from the accepted answer. And I think `encode("utf-8").decode("ascii")` reveal the relation between string and bytes in Python2.

Comment: confuse cuz, 2 or 3 was not specified.

Answer (score 0):

You should encode them to bytes first and decode them to ascii string.

```
l = list()

for item in d:
    temp = dict()
    for key, value in item.items():
        temp[key.encode("utf-8").decode("ascii")] = value.encode("utf-8").decode("ascii")
    l.append(temp)
```